# Defining functions in a Javascript loop and using variables set in the loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm trying to define functions in a loop in javascript...

```
for (var i in myArray) {
  Object.defineProperty(object, "field"+i, { ... });
}
```

...and each function needs to make use of a variable which is set in that loop...

```
for (var i in myArray) {
  Object.defineProperty(object, "field"+i, { 
    get: function() { return "some operation" + myArray[i]; }
  });
}
```

...but this doesn't work because when I call the functions (long after they're defined), `i` evaluates to the last item in the `myArray`. All of the functions I defined in the loop return the same (erroneous) value.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish my aim: make use of `myArray[i]` within my getter function?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Loop not working correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318554/jquery-loop-not-working-correctly)

Comment: @procrastinator, awesome. Thank you. I used a factory function to solve the problem.

Comment: Off-topic: `for..in` loops are a bad way of iterating arrays. You should use ES6 `for..of` (currently only supported by FF), or a `for(var i=0, l=myArray.length; i<l; ++i)` loop.

Comment: Not an awesome-sounding idea. Avoid array indices, which are more powerful than array elements? Support only a single browser? How about you give some indication of why `for..in` loops are a 'bad' way of iterating arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be done as following

```
for (var i in myArray) 
  {
  var getter=function yourName () { return "some operation" + yourName.data;}
  getter.data=myArray[i];
  Object.defineProperty(object, "field"+i, { 
  get: getter});
  }
```

you can define a function with

```
 var test=function testit () {}
```

testit can be use to call the function from inside the function.
its a locale variable inside, its replacing arguments.callee which is depreacted in  strict mode.

test is defined outside the function to call it from outside

Answer (score 1):

I created an extra closure by  using a factory function:

```
function makeGetter(myString) {
  return function () { return "some operation" + myString; };
}
for (var i in myArray) {
  Object.defineProperty(object, "field"+i, { 
    get: makeGetter(myArray[i])
  });
}
```